# How to simplify an if/else statement with assignments on it

Tags: javascript, if-statement, ecmascript-6, coding-style

I was wondering if there is any way to simplify this if/else statement, just curious about finding an inline way of solving this (variables are this trivial due to experimenting purposes:

```
var a = false;
var b = false;
var condition = true;

if (condition) {
  a = true;
} else {
  b = true;
}
```

I took it as a code challenge with a colleague, join us if feeling like that, cheers :)

Comment: This should work if I am not mistaken `condition ? (a = true) : (b = true)`

Comment: Isn't the whole point of a challenge like this for you to figure it out yourself? What do you gain by getting the Internet to answer it for you?

Comment: ternary will work, but is bad practice

Comment: ternary would work, I thought the same, but we are getting some eslint hinters for it, thank you anyway!
also @Barmar I just thought it would be nice to hear some third-party opinions

Comment: I'll give you a hint: an assignment can be used as an expression.

Comment: And this will allow you to assign two variables in the same command, if there's some relationship between them.

Answer (score 5):

What about

```
var a =condition;
var b = !a;
```

Comment: Based on the OP's code, this would set `a` to `true` and `b` to `false` all the time.

Comment: I mean their code also sets  a to true all the time as well, it does it in a more compact manner now.

Comment: sounds good but I was looking for some inline way of doing it to make it look as clean as possible

Answer (score 4):

You can use destructuring to assign true / false according to `condition`:

```js
const condition = true;

const [a, b] = condition ? [true, false] : [false, true]

console.log({ a, b });
```

And you can optimize it to:

```js
const condition = true;

const [a, b] =  [condition, !condition]

console.log({ a, b });
```

And using default values, you can shorten it a bit more, although it's a slight abuse of the default values:

```js
const condition = true;

const [a, b = !a] =  [condition]

console.log({ a, b });
```

Comment: That is definitely an interesting answer!